# Set state inside auth class?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have the following problem.  I want the message to be the correct exception type.  i can only use set state within my sign in (because my auth class is not a statlesswidget)class and pass a message there with set state(), but the same for all errors.  I've been trying for 9 hours and I can't figure it out. Please help.  so I just want the correct exception to be displayed.Something like  „The Email adress is badly formated“.the problem is i it dont let me to set the error message be the real error message and i dont know how to fix it

```
  Widget _buildLoginBtn() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RawMaterialButton(
          elevation: 5.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text(
            'LOGIN',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF527DAA),
              letterSpacing: 1.5,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            
            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              print('valid');
              setState(() => loading = false);
              dynamic result =
                  await _auth.signIN(email, password);
                  if (result == null) {
                setState(() => error = 'Check your Input');
                loading= false;
              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
```

```
 Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {
   try {
     FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
             email: email.trim(), password: password)).user;
   } catch (e) {
     return null;
   }
   if (user != null) {
     print(user);
   }
   return null;
 }
```

So after im following @ Gerpea advice I Get the following error when im just trying to catch the error without the statement on FIREBASEAUTHERROR and when im trying with the statement. When im trying to update my auth and cloud and core it gets me another error.And I can really say if the he ignored the catch block because it don't starts actually when im starting I get as I said before the error in console Im using:

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
 firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
 cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
 firebase_core_web: ^0.2.1+3
 provider: ^4.3.3
 flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1
 flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
 auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
 firebase_core: ^0.4.0
 get_it: ^5.0.6
```

The error ist this:

```
Invalid depfile: /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/project neu2/flutter_application_2/.dart_tool/flutter_build/7e96e6ced6aa40f9bcd60c2328bbea3e/kernel_snapshot.d
^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';

^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.2.1+3/lib/src/interop/utils/js_interop.dart:24:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
 if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'toDateString')) {
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.2.1+3/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:39:26: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.

     map[key] = dartify(util.getProperty(jsObject, key), customDartify);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.2.1+3/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:65:17: Error: Method not found: 'newObject'.
   var jsMap = util.newObject();
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.2.1+3/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:67:7: Error: Method not found: 'setProperty'.
     util.setProperty(jsMap, key, jsify(value, customJsify));
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.2.1+3/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:73:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
```

OKafter trying the second correction that @Gerpea send I get the same error so I decide to update to the newest versions go auth.
No I got some problems but I think that's maybe be easyler to correct
but don't really how maybe you know?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web_interop.dart';

import 'package:flutter_application_2/models/user.dart';

class AuthService {
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 String error;
 //create user obj based on FirebasedUser
 User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
   return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
 }

 //auth change user stream
 Stream<User> get user {
   return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
 }

//sign in anon
 Future signInAnon() async {
   try {
     AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
     FirebaseUser user = result.user;
     return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     return null;
   }
 }
 

//sign in with passwort and email
 Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email.trim(), 
      password: password,
    )).user;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch(e.code) {
      case 'user-not-found': {
        return 'No user found';
      }
      default: {
        return 'Unexpected error!';
      }
    }
  }
  
  return null;
 }

//register with passwort an email
 Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
   FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
           email: email, password: password)) .user;
   try {
     await user.sendEmailVerification();
     return user.uid;
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString);
     return null;
   }
 }

 //sign out
 Future signOut() async {
   try {
     return await _auth.signOut();
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     return null;
   }
 }

 //resetpassword
 Future<void> sendPasswordResetEmail(String email) async {
   try {
     return await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     return null;
   }
 }
}
```

that's the exceptions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SAcJ.png)

OK now it logs very good I just have 2 exceptions. Code looks like that:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/models/user.dart' as Model;


class AuthService {
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 String error;
 //create user obj based on FirebasedUser
 Model.User _userFromFirebaseUser(Model.User user) {
   return user != null ? Model.User(uid: user.uid) : null;
 }

 //auth change user stream
 Stream<Model.User> get user {
   return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
 }

//sign in anon
 Future signInAnon() async {
   try {
     UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
     User user = result.user;
     return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     return null;
   }
 }
 

//sign in with passwort and email
 Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email.trim(), 
      password: password,
    )).user;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch(e.code) {
      case 'user-not-found': {
        return 'No user found';
      }
      default: {
        return 'Unexpected error!';
      }
    }
  }
  
  return null;
 }

//register with passwort an email
 Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
   User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
           email: email, password: password)) .user;
   try {
     await user.sendEmailVerification();
     return user.uid;
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString);
     return null;
   }
 }

 //sign out
 Future signOut() async {
   try {
     return await _auth.signOut();
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     return null;
   }
 }

 //resetpassword
 Future<void> sendPasswordResetEmail(String email) async {
   try {
     return await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     return null;
   }
 }
}
```

And EXCEptions like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az9oy.png)

@Gerpea
So here's my code

```
Future<String> signUp(String email, String password, String fullname,String user) async {

    try {
  ( await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(), password: password,)).user.sendEmailVerification();


 await DatbaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData('username', 'fullname', 'Passwort', 'Email');


    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
```

And the method from YouTube:

```
Future registerWithEmailAndAPassword(String email, String,Passwort)async {
try{
AuthResult result = await.createUserWithEmailAndPassowrd(email:email,password:password);
FirebaseUser user =result.user;

await DatabaseService(uid:user.uid).updateUserData('0','new crew member',100);
return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
}catch (e){
```

Comment: Where are you declared messages to exceptions?

Comment: you mean like created messages ? in that case I don't have that. How im doing that ? And how to implement in my code. I just have a sidebox with have text settings so the message will be displayed wen I use set.Should I updated my post with that ?

Comment: What do you mean as "correct exception"?

Comment: I mean like The email address is badly formatted. I just have "default"one exception and that's check your input, but you know the user not really know what's wrong.

Comment: OH man THANKS alot  you solving it. GENIUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*signInWithEmailAndPassword()* method in case of error will throw a [FirebaseAuthException](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FirebaseAuthException-class.html) which contain *code* field with error code.

The full list of errors for this method can be found [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html).

So you can rewrite you method a bit, to **return an error message instead just *null*.**

```dart
 Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {
   try {
     User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: email.trim(), 
       password: password,
     )).user;
   } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     switch(e.code) {
       case 'user-not-found': {
         return 'No user found';
       }
       default: {
         return 'Unexpected error!';
       }
     }
   }
   
   return null;
 }
```

Now this method return *null* if there is no error and *String* if some error occurs.

**Use this in *onPressed*** callback.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    print('valid');

    String authError = await _auth.signIN(email, password);
    if (authError != null) {
      setState(() => error = authError);
    }

    setState(() => loading = false);
  }
}
```

**firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5**

This is a bit outdated and has some problems, so it will be better if you
will upgrade your dependencies.

But if you can't upgrade. This should work.

```dart
 Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {
   try {
     FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: email.trim(), 
       password: password,
     )).user;
   } on AuthException catch (e) {
     switch(e.code) {
       case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND': {
         return 'No user found';
       }
       default: {
         return 'Unexpected error!';
       }
     }
   } catch(e) {
     return 'Some error that FirebaseAuth do not catch'!;
   }

   return null;
 }
```

List of error codes can be found [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/0.14.0+5/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html).

Comment: Ok I've done what you say but it don't let me to use FirebaseAuthException.Just Firebase FirebaseAuth or FirebaseError. And when I use them I get a long error list?What im doing wrong? will you see the exception? thanks

Comment: Which version of firebase_auth you are using? Can you clarify please, Is catch block with FirebaseAuthException just ignored and instead of them some other block catching? What will happen if you remove on FirebaseAuthException and try to see the error?

Comment: I Add that post so you can se what you wanna see thanks again.

Comment: I update my answer, hope this will help you.

Comment: About error when upgrade dependencies. Try to checkout you pubspec.yaml file for typo or indentantion errors. Then run flutter clean and try upgrade again. In your snippet with dependencies for example you hav an invalid white space character on each line except first.

Comment: ok I updated my post again maybe now you know how to fix it. will be great and I know that's pubsec file is correct because my app it already was running before want to fix the message. hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yep, now I understand. You code use old firebase_auth API. There wa change since firebase_auth 0.18.0. So the error says that you have duplicate user definition one in firebase_auth package and one in your user model file. Try to use aliases for import: import 'package:flutter_application_2/models/user.dart' as Model; and then instead of User use Model.User. Also you need change FirebaseUser to User and AuthResult to UserCredentail. In version 0.18.0 firebase_auth just renamed this classes.

Comment: OK hopefully last exception and edit the last post please check out

Comment: Now to listen auth state changes you need to use FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges() which return stream, so you can write _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser). Also I would recomend you to use concrete version of dependencies, like: firebase_auth: 0.20.1.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I should pass it because I think im doing it wrong.maybe edit the code. It will be great.

Comment: I create gist for you, check it here https://gist.github.com/Gerpea/cc8cc840a5cf55da43145be82b254700. Your method _userFromFirebaseUser should take User as parameter instead of Model.User.

Comment: OK i solved my Problem thanks a lot man. GENIUS!

Comment: Hey sorry that im asking again you something. But I'm Stuck. Im trying to load the data to Cloud firestorm. So I found a video on YouTube but like he doing it dont function for my code . So maybe you can help. Will be great .I updated my post so you can send how it looks on YouTube and how my code looks. thanks.